# Unable to swap the variables using perl?

Tags: perl

---

Here by i tried to swap the variables using perl.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $v1=23;
 my $v2=43;
 $v1,$v2)=($v2,$v1)
 print $v1,$v2;
```

Error:

```
syntax error at exchange.pl line 7, near ")
print"
Execution of exchange.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Excepted output:

```
43,23
```

Comment: know nothing about perl.. but I think you need a `(` and a `;` here -> `$v1,$v2)=($v2,$v1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot open parens and semicolon:

```
($v1,$v2)=($v2,$v1);
print $v1,$v2;
```

Expected output should be 4323 (4 chars and no comma), not 43,23.

To print 43,23:

```
print "$v1,$v2";
```